# Typo3 12.4.7: Try to upload an Extention (*.zip) to my site - get error

Tags: typo3-12.x

I wanted to install a external extention [web2pdf Extention](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/web2pdf) and I get this error in my working Typo3 12.4.7 System. I have not installed it via composer but by legacy method.
[image: UPLOAD Extention]
Error:
[image: Do get Error: Ext web2pdf is not available.]

I also tried it with another EXT - same result.
What can I do, that I can install EXTENTIONS without composer by uploading the ZIPs?